# Not capturing return value from stored proc in asp classic

Tags: javascript, sql-server, ajax, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

Sorry for the long post but I wanted to include all details.

I have a JavaScript function using ajax that calls some asp code which in turn calls a stored procedure to simply check if a record already exists.  If it does exist one image appears, if it doesn't exist a different image appears.  For some reason I am unable to capture the results in my asp variable, it returns empty, which makes the call always returns false.  I have tested the SQL procedure by itself and it works so the data is there.  Here is the code which will explain better.

**Stored Proc:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserName_Get] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @UserName nvarchar(50)
    ,@FacilityID INT
    ,@UserNameExists INT OUT
AS

BEGIN
    SELECT @UserNameExists= ISNULL((SELECT UserID FROM MyTable WHERE FacilityID = @FacilityID AND Username = @UserName),0)

END
```

**Classic ASP code:**

```vb
<% Response.Buffer = True %>
<!-- #include file="../../_app_init.asp" -->

<%
Dim action, p_UserName
action = SqlSanitizeStr(trim(request("action")))
'dim UserNameExists

If action = "CheckUserName" Then
    ' Check to see if this username already exists for this facility
    ' This is an Ajax routine to check if the username already exists at the current facility or not. Returns "False" if UserName does not exist.

    p_UserName=SqlSanitizeStr(trim(request("UserName")))


    Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = DB_CONN
    objCmd.CommandText = "UserName_Get"
    objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    objCmd.Parameters.Append objCmd.CreateParameter("@UserName",        adLongVarChar,      adParamInput,   50        , p_UserName)
    objCmd.Parameters.Append objCmd.CreateParameter("@FacilityID",      adInteger,      adParamInput,           ,   LOGIN_FACILITY_ID)
    objCmd.Parameters.Append objCmd.CreateParameter("@UserNameExists",      adInteger,      adParamReturnValue)
    objCmd.Execute ,, adExecuteNoRecords
    UserNameExists = objCmd.Parameters("@UserNameExists").Value ' Get value of output parameter



    If UserNameExists>0 Then

        Response.Write ("True")

    Else
        Response.Write ("False")

    End If

End If



%>
```

**JavaScript Ajax Call**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


  function CheckUserName(UserName_element) {


    var UserName = UserName_element.value;
    var valid_UserName_image = document.getElementById('valid_UserName_image');
    var invalid_UserName_image = document.getElementById('invalid_UserName_image');

    $j.ajax({
        data: { action: 'CheckUserName', p_UserName: UserName },
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'page_logic/_check_username_ajax.asp',
        success: function (result) {

            //Just to see what the return value is
            alert(result)

            if (result == "True") {


                valid_UserName_image.style.display = "none";
                invalid_UserName_image.style.display = "inline";

            }
            else {

                valid_UserName_image.style.display = "inline";
                invalid_UserName_image.style.display = "none";

                }

            }
        }
    );

}


</script>
```

I put in alert(result) to see what was being returned, it is always empty.

If I change the stored proc to simply

```
 SELECT @UserNameExists=0 or SELECT @UserNameExists=1
```

It will return a value, but of course that is hard coding the result and not actually getting records from the DB.

Comment: `SqlSanitizeStr` where does this function come from?

Comment: It is a function that written before I got on board the project, it basically strips our single apostrophes' and other characters that SQL doesn't like.  It is not that effective but it is used all over this project so I have to live with it.  We are slowly converting it to .Net but for now we have to deal with classic asp because this is what is in production and is used by many people.

Comment: That is also why you see $j., in stead of just $.  The person who started this actually began building his own framework in classic asp.  It is difficult to work with.

Comment: I've changed your query from the stored procedure into a query that can be run in my sql 2014 db. It returns 1 or 0. How is LOGIN_FACILITY_ID supplied?

Comment: Your appends are incorrect is my guess, they're missing `( )`, as with your execute statement. However these can be copy paste errors

Comment: It is a variable that is stored in server cache at the beginning of the day when the program initializes.  All the customers have a distinct URL that is used to query and then load the LOGIN_FACILITY_ID.  We have to do this because if that ID ever was passed in a URL a savy user could change it and possibly access data of another customer.  We store a lot in server cache because our web server has incredible amounts of processing power and ram and we utilize it to reduce the number of DB calls.

Comment: Could you post an example of the correct syntax with the ( ).  I am slow working with classic asp and I thought it may have been dumb syntax error.

Comment: Whoever changed the title is right but its not their place to change the context of the question even if the issue is the OPs miss understanding of return and output parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the mix up between the use of `OUTPUT` and `RETURN` in stored procedures in SQL Server.

To clear things up, your stored procedure is expecting an `OUTPUT` parameter instead of a `RETURN` value which is something different.

Try changing your output parameter statement to;

```vb
objCmd.Parameters.Append objCmd.CreateParameter("@UserNameExists", adInteger, adParamOutput)
```

For reference `adParamReturnValue` is used to return the value of the `RETURN` statement if used and is limited to `INT` values.

Comment: This answer may have helped, however strangely enough the issue that solved it for good was in my stored procedure.  I was setting the return variable using "Select @variable"  I changed it to "Set @variable" and the asp page picked it up.  Trial and Error.....

Comment: @Michael Remember return value is something different to avoid confusion call them output parameters. Did you use `adParamOutput` in the end?, interesting point about `SELECT` versus `SET`, can't say I've come across that before.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using adParamOutput.